# Why does my break statement break "too far"?

Tags: loops, powershell, break

Here's a snippet of my code (based on [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35085863)):

```
$rgdNames = (Get-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName "$azureResGrpName").DeploymentName
$siblings = $rgdNames | Where-Object{$_ -match "^($hostname)(\d+)$" }
if ($siblings) {
    # Make a list of all numbers in the list of hostnames
    $serials = @()
    foreach ($sibling in $siblings) {
        # $sibling -split ($sibling -split '\d+$') < split all digits from end, then strip off everything at the front
        # Then convert it to a number and add that to $serials
        $hostnumber = [convert]::ToInt32([string]$($sibling -split ($sibling -split '\d+$'))[1], 10)
        $serials += $hostnumber
    }
    (1..$siblingsMax) | foreach { # Iterate over all valid serial numbers
        if (!$serials.Contains($_)) { # Stop when we find a serial number that isn't in the list of existing hosts
            $serial = $_
             # break # FIXME: For some reason, this break statement breaks "too far"
        }
    }
} else {
    $serial = 1
}
write-output("serial = $serial") # does not print
# ...more statements here, but they're never called :(
```

I have been looking at it for a while, but can't figure out why the `break` statement (if un-commented) stops my program instead of just breaking out of its `foreach` loop. Is there something about `foreach` that I'm not aware of, or does `break` just work differently than it would in Java?

For the time being, I'm working around this using an extra `if` test, and it doesn't mean (too) much that the loop runs its entire length. But it's ugly!

Comment: Err, no I don't, but I made a formatting mistake after pasting my code into this post. Sorry, and thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This construct:

```
(1..$siblingsMax) | foreach { # Iterate over all valid serial numbers
    # do stuff
}
```

is ***NOT*** a `foreach` loop - it's a pipeline with a call to the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet (aliased as `foreach`) - and keywords designed to interrupt the control flow of a loop (like `break` or `continue`) will NOT act in the same way in these two different cases.

Use a proper `foreach` loop and break will behave as you expect:

```
foreach($i in 1..$siblingsMax){
    # do stuff
    if($shouldBreak)
    {
        break
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can abuse the fact that [`continue` behaves like you would expect `break` in a `ForEach-Object`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760013/why-does-continue-behave-like-break-in-a-foreach-object) process block:

```
(1..$siblingsMax) | foreach { # Iterate over all valid serial numbers
    if($shouldBreak)
    {
        continue
    }
}
```

although I would *strongly* discourage this approach (it'll only lead to more confusion)

Comment: Thanks for educating me on `foreach`. I've reworded the loop to your formula. However, the thing still operates the same way... :(

Comment: That's odd. Could you add the "reworded" version to your question?

Comment: AFAIK, in absence of loops, `continue` behave exactly line `break`: it return you in prompt. I think, it is not what OP want.